# Query selection method -.ready() Vs Utility method - $.ready()

Tags: javascript, jquery

As per the [jQueryDoc](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/dollar-object-vs-function/) terminology, `.ready()` is referred as **query selection method** sitting in `jQuery.prototype`. For ex- `$(document).ready()`

As [jQueryDoc](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/dollar-object-vs-function/) says: *Methods in the `$` namespace are generally utility-type methods, and do not work with selections*

What is the purpose of `jQuery.ready()` **utility method**?

Answer (score 4):

Plain `$.ready()` is not a utility method. It is an internal, undocumented, event handler for the `ready` routine.

Its source code (jQuery 1.11.3) is:

```
// Handle when the DOM is ready
ready: function( wait ) {

    // Abort if there are pending holds or we're already ready
    if ( wait === true ? --jQuery.readyWait : jQuery.isReady ) {
        return;
    }

    // Make sure body exists, at least, in case IE gets a little overzealous (ticket #5443).
    if ( !document.body ) {
        return setTimeout( jQuery.ready );
    }

    // Remember that the DOM is ready
    jQuery.isReady = true;

    // If a normal DOM Ready event fired, decrement, and wait if need be
    if ( wait !== true && --jQuery.readyWait > 0 ) {
        return;
    }

    // If there are functions bound, to execute
    readyList.resolveWith( document, [ jQuery ] );

    // Trigger any bound ready events
    if ( jQuery.fn.triggerHandler ) {
        jQuery( document ).triggerHandler( "ready" );
        jQuery( document ).off( "ready" );
    }
}
```

As a private implementation detail, you can safely ignore it.

Comment: Are all the methods under `$` are not utility methods?

Comment: @overexchange, all the documented ones are (although *utility* is quite vague), but there are also a lot of hooks and internal stuff in the `$` object. `dir($)` in your console will show you.

Comment: I typed `console.dir($)`, but how do I know which properties are hooks?

Comment: @overexchange, sometimes they have `Hooks` in their names (the documented ones do). The rest you have to tell from reading the source code. Try it -- it's actually very well-commented.

Comment: @Pointy It is not appropriate to mention that `dir($)` are all utitlity methods in this [documentation](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/dollar-object-vs-function/). Can you help me raise a ticket?

Comment: @overexchange, actually I believe that link is only referring to the *documented* methods of the `$` object, as is usually the case in this context. I don't think a ticket would be warranted.